# Make a list and QuerySet comparable

Tags: django, django-queryset

First I know that similar questions have been asked ( I looked at them) but none of them answered my question. If this question has been answered please send me the link and I will delete this one.

So I have this function in which I would like to compare how often a Word has been used in both lists/QuerySets. Since the don't have the same structure I cannot do that.

```
productArr = self.tags.all() # is a QuerySet 
CustomerArr = self.user.userprofile.I_want.split(",")[:3]
```

`productArr:(<QuerySet [<Tag: and>, <Tag: Jeans>, <Tag: Love>, <Tag: Leg>]`, 
`CustomerArr:[u'Funny', u' and', u' 1234']`

```
Model for CustomerArr:
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    I_want = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=‚example‘)


Model for productArr:
class Product(models.Model):
    tags = TaggableManager(verbose_name="tags",blank=False)
    …
    CustomerArr = self.user.userprofile.I_want.split(",")[:3]
    productArr = self.tags.all()
    def func(a, b):
        global favVal 
        favVal = 0
        for i in a:
            if i in b:
                #print('hey')
                favVal += 1 
        return False
    func(productArr, CustomerArr)
```

so I tried to `productArrlist = list(productArr)` and similar things to make those two comparable but it did not work. I hope somebody can help me out here.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

```
self.tags.values_list('you_field_name', flat=True)
```

**UPDATE:**

With your model, I saw you are using django-taggit. In API of this, you have [names()](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)

```
productArr = self.tags.names()
```

Comment: I saw this before and it did not work out for me. when I do this on productArr I still get a querySet and on CustomerArr its not usable(I don't get any outcome in the admin).

Comment: This didn't work for a reason. What do you do on productArr exactly ?
Can you share your models ? And what did you except in productArr ?

Comment: please look at my updated answer. In productArr I have a list of tags provided by the user. in CustomerArr I have a list of normal strings. I just thought maybe I should transform the CustomerArr also to a tag so its also a querySet...

Comment: take an upvote and the green arrow for your effort sir. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to help you. The solution with names() works for you ?

Comment: yes it works like a charm. he compares the tags and gives points just like I wanted it...